# Pandas - Map multiple rows from another DF to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I'm trying to migrate data from one `df1` to my main `df`.

They share a common key - and I want to store the values from a `df1` row into a `df` column. This I could do.. **however** `df1` can have multiple rows (max 5) that share the common key and **I would like to store each row in an individual column.**

Using an example:

df

```
index  key   datacol 
  1    1AA    data1 
  2    1AB    data2
  3    1AC    data3
```

df1

```
index  key   newdata 
  1    1AA    new1
  2    1AB    new2
  3    1AB    new3
  4    1AB    new4 
  5    1AC    new5
  6    1AC    new6
```

Output:

```
index  key   datacol newcol1 newcol2 newcol3
  1    1AA    data1   new1
  2    1AB    data2   new2    new3    new4
  3    1AC    data3   new5    new6
```

Appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, can do

```
d = df2.groupby('key', as_index=False).agg(list)
x = pd.concat([d.newdata.apply(pd.Series), d.key],1).set_index('key')
pd.merge(df.set_index('key'),x, right_index=True, left_index=True)

        index   datacol  0      1       2
key                 
1AA      1      data1    new1   NaN     NaN
1AB      2      data2    new2   new3    new4
1AC      3      data3    new5   new6    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge firstly

```
newdf=df.merge(df1,how='right')
```

Then using `cumcount` create the help key, then the question is looks like `pivot`

```
finaldf= newdf.assign(helpkey=newdf.groupby('key').cumcount()).set_index(['key','datacol','helpkey']).newdata.unstack(fill_value='')
finaldf
Out[410]: 
helpkey         0     1     2
key datacol                  
1AA data1    new1            
1AB data2    new2  new3  new4
1AC data3    new5  new6
```